# Does picasso automatically remove unused images from picasso-cache directory?

Tags: android, picasso

Does picasso automatically remove unused images from the picasso-cache directory, or do we have to manually call `Picasso.with(getActivity()).invalidate(file);` to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Basically Picasso can use of the two following HTTP clients: OkHttp library or `UrlConnection` class. If you OkHttp, Picasso will load images via its `OkHttpDownloader` class and if you use `UrlConnection` then Picasso will make use of the `UrlConnectionDownloader`.

Now, in both cases downloaders have their caching mechanisms. `UrlConnectionDownloader` sets its caching like this:

```
  if (cache == null) {
    long maxSize = Utils.calculateDiskCacheSize(cacheDir);
    cache = HttpResponseCache.install(cacheDir, maxSize);
  }
```

... and `OkHttpDownloader` sets caching like this:

```
this(defaultOkHttpClient());
try {
  client.setCache(new com.squareup.okhttp.Cache(cacheDir, maxSize));
} catch (IOException ignored) {
}
```

We can see that in both cases we have a caching directory with size limit. So, the answer to your question is: yes, Picasso does remove cached images if the total size of cached images exceeded the cache's size limit.